# Restore background after sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite, getimagedata, putimagedata

I'm attempting to make a game, and I've got some sprites that will overlap each other. When clearing the sprite's area with `clearRect`, any sprite behind it will disappear as if the foreground sprite wasn't transparent. However, if I try to save and restore the area behind the sprite using `get/putImageData`, weird things start to happen. Part of the sprites in various places do not get "undrawn", other parts seem to be broken up and yards away, and other sprites get smeared. Here's a code chunk:

```
var anim = function()
{
    if(gtiming < Date.now() % 1000)
        timing = (Date.now() % 1000) - gtiming;

    if(stage == 1)
    {
        ugcnt = ugcnt + timing;

        if(mleft == true)
        {
            acc = acc - 0.25;
        }
        else if(mright == true)
        {
            acc = acc + 0.25;
        }
        else
        {
            if(acc < 0 || acc > 0) acc = acc / 1.1;
        }
        if(kyx < 0)
        {
            kyx = 0;
            acc = -acc;
        }
        else if(kyx > 432)
        {
            kyx = 432;
            acc = -acc;
        }
        if(kyblk != null)
            xbios.putImageData(kyblk, kyx, 155);
        kyblk = null;
        kyx = kyx + acc;
        kyblk = xbios.getImageData(kyx, 155, 208, 245);
        xbios.drawImage(kyk[Math.floor(kyf)], 0, 0, 416, 490, kyx, 155, 208, 245);

        if(ugcnt > mus[r][1] * 1000)
        {
            ugcnt = 0;
            ugobj.push(new ugnaut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 640), -208, "L"));
        }
        ugobj.forEach(testug);


        kyf = kyf + ((timing / 1000) * (mus[r][1] * 240));
        if(kyf > 119)
            kyf = kyf - 119;
    }

    gtiming = Date.now() % 1000;
    if(stage > 0)
        requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
function ugnaut(x, y, f)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.f = f;
    this.fr = 0;
    this.blk = null;

    this.set=function()
    {
        if(this.blk != null)
            xbios.putImageData(this.blk, this.x, this.y);
        this.blk = null;
        if(f == "L")
        {
            this.y++;
            this.blk = xbios.getImageData(this.x, this.y, 179, 208);
            xbios.drawImage(ugf[this.fr], 0, 0, 179, 208, this.x, this.y, 179, 208);
            this.fr++;
            if(this.fr > 44) this.fr = 0;
        }
    }
    this.getx = function()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    this.gety = function()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    this.getf = function()
    {
        return this.f;
    }
}
function testug(item, index)
{
    if(item.getx() > -180 && item.getx() < 640 && item.gety() > -224 && item.gety() < 400)
    {
        item.set();
    }
    else
    {
        item = null;
        ugobj.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

For those wondering, yes, I did call the Canvas 2D Context `xbios`. Just felt like a fun name at the time. Anyways, from my understanding having a `this` inside the "object" `ugnaut` the value it holds will be local to that object's instance, and so I assume each `ugnaut` will hold its own background information in `this.blk`, but am I wrong? What other methods should I use?

Comment: If you are serious about building a game, do not reinvent the wheel! use a game engine, there are plenty of Open Source ones: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: Ok. Guess I'll try to learn one of those, whichever's document is best to learn from. I'm assuming this thing called `update()` will update every frame (like `RAF()`), so if I want seamless looping (or dynamic) music I'd do those "calculations" in there. Here's the entirety of the code if you are interested: http://edwardleuf.org/Games/_mine/KICKUGNT/

Comment: Just clear the whole canvas and redraw everything at every frame. By the time getImageData putImageData gets processed you could already have drawn thousands of sprites.

Comment: @Kaiido I was hoping for something a little more optimized. Right now, it may work, but imagine if I had a field of tiles in the background. To redraw all those would slow things down.